# Dynamic VLANs Assignment using MAB, LDAP and ACS Server

Tags: ldap, acs, radius, vlan

I'm new to this forum. This is my first post. Now I'm working on how to dynamically assign switch ports to their respective VLAN by using MAB with ACS server. I've LDAP database that contains greater numbers of end device 's MAC addresses. I want to use Mac address bypass feature in ACS server which will send query to LDAP database to authenticate the mac address. If the mac address is valid then i want to read a specific information which is VLAN ID that stored in LDAP and send back to the switch that end devices connected. From the reply from ACS server, the switch now can read the VLAN ID and match with its own VLAN database and set that particular ports to that vlan.

My question: Is it possible to do this in ACS server by using MAB?

1. Is it possible to do this in ACS server by using MAB?
2. If no, is there any other technology that can help to actualize my idea above?
3. In nutshell, can I automatically change VLAN in the switch based on the information stored in LDAP database such end device's mac address and vlan ID for that particular mac address by using ACS server?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Welcome. Try to space a little your text. You write twice "Is it possible to do this in ACS server by using MAB?".